# Qt / QMake 5.5 cannot add framework

Tags: qt, frameworks, qmake

I need to add a 3rd party framework to my Qt project.  Through Qt 5.4, I was able to use this method:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/path/to/framework/directory/
```

Followed by...

```
LIBS += -framework TheFramework
```

Now, this fails.  It produces this compile error:

```
error: framework not found -L/Users/xxxxxxx/Qt5.5/5.5/ios/plugins/platforms
```

The compile output also shows this, which I think is somehow the cause:

```
warning: skipping file '/Users/xxxxxx/QtProjects/xxxxx/build-xxxxx-iphoneos_clang_Qt_5_5_0_for_iOS-Release/MYFRAMEWORKNAME' (unexpected file type 'text' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: That appears to be correct according to the documentation. I saw in a post on another forum that the solution was to add the path to the framework to LIBS  `LIBS += -F/path/to/framework/directory` Here is the [link](http://forum.qt.io/topic/40375/solved-can-t-add-ios-opencv-framework-in-a-qt-project).

Comment: Don't touch QMAKE_LFLAGS directly. Add the path to LIBS.

Comment: Good suggestion, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found something of a "work around" for my particular situation. The framework I wanted to include was ZLib for iOS.  Apparently, the Qt 5.5 for iOS framework must have the library included, because I no longer require the framework inclusion...

```
contains(DEFINES, INCLUDE_ZLIB) {
    contains(DEFINES, QT_VER_5_5_OR_NEWER) {
        # Already in Qt?
    }
    else {
        QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F$${top_srcdir}/zlib/zlib/ios/framework/
        LIBS += -framework zlib
    }
}
```